# Jenkins: How to set a schedule for a parametrized job?

Tags: jenkins

I want to set a schedule for a parametrized Jenkins job to start in different time with different parameters, but I can not find the correct syntax for this. I would like to have something like that:

```
30 1 * * * % VAR1=VALUE1, VAR2=VALUE2
30 2 * * * % VAR1=VALUE3, VAR2=VALUE4
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the plugin README:
[parameterized-scheduler-plugin README.md](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md#configuration-example)

```
  # leave spaces where you want them around the parameters. They'll be trimmed.
  # we let the build run with the default name
  5 * * * * % furniture=chair;color=black
  # now, let's override that default name and use Mr. Rubble.
  10 * * * * % furniture=desk; color=yellow; name=barney
```

Not explicitly documented, but the example and the [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/parameterizedscheduler/ParameterParser.java#L21) show it to be  `PAIR_SEPARATOR= ";"`

See also [this "bug"](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/11902/13379) - [JENKINS-22129](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22129) and [JENKINS--53220](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53220) and [more](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/#issues)