# Parameterized Scheduler with File parameters - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I pass multiple files as parameters to my jenkins job. I have scheduled the job to run at regular intervals. I have installed the parameterized-scheduler plugin but I am unable to figure out the syntax for scheduling the job with the files as parameters.

If my file names are a.js, b.js, c.js. What would be the syntax for me to use the parameterized scheduler?

Is there another approach to solving this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins: How to set a schedule for a parametrized job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858574/jenkins-how-to-set-a-schedule-for-a-parametrized-job)

Comment: It does not Ian. Because I don't know the syntax to scheduling the job that depends on File Parameters. It has examples for many params but File parmas.

Comment: Technically, you don't have a file. You have a string, which corresponds to to the name of a file. You are then passing that as a string parameter to the job into variable, params.FILE, which your job does something with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer to this question although I have found a better approach.

The right way to solve this problem is to upload the files on a cloud repository that can be downloaded/cloned to the workspace during a build and then use the files.

So, I have uploaded the files to a github repo which I am cloning during a build and using them.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for parametrized scheduler:

```
*/2 * * * * %FILE=a.js
1-59/2 * * * * %FILE=b.js
* * * * * %FILE=c.js
```

Here, `FILE` is string parameter which accepts the name of file.

> Note: Please change the interval accordingly.

Comment: I can use all three params in the same build?

Comment: Yes. You can use

Comment: @ManojDeshpande As mentioned by Sourav you can use multiple parameters please check https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/ for more details.